# How to show progress view for task getting executed in background thread

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, nsurlsession

I am using `NSURLSession's dataTaskWithRequest` to download data to my app.

Currently I show an *activity view overlay* on my view controller when my app downloads data from web server.

My user requested me to show a custom animation that tracks the execution completion of download process.

I know that `dataTaskWithRequest` is `asynchronous` and executes in `background thread`. I also know that I can `NSURLSessionDelegate` method

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {}
```

to track progress of data being uploaded. So, I was wondering if there is any way to assign a progress view for download activity.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the delegate method

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten writ: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64)
```

which works pretty much the same way as `didSendBodyData`

It won't link the download to your progress view but it should be simple to set the `progressView.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)`
inside that delegate method.